# Sendkey ("{ENTER}") not working when automating Internet explorer

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, sendkeys

`Sendkey ("{ENTER}")` not entering data into website from excel

I need to use it since form does not have a button to click

```
Sub FillInternetForm()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Navigate "http://reference.medscape.com/drug-interactionchecker"
IE.Visible = True
While IE.Busy
DoEvents
Wend

Set TrackID = IE.Document.getelementbyid("MDICtextbox")
TrackID.Value = "Aspirin"
IE.Visible = True
SendKeys ("{ENTER}") 

End Sub
```

Note that, if I change enter to other command such as `{BS}` or Backspace it works but not enter

Comment: I suggest to locate the `JS` function (`onkeyup/onkeydown/onchange`) that handles the "enter" key press, and call it.

Comment: How do I do that please?

Comment: <input type="text" id="MDICtextbox" class="intcheck_input" />
            <div id="MDICilfulllist">
              <div id="MDICildruglist"> 
                <strong>Drugs</strong>
                <p id="MDICildrugnor">No Results</p>
                <ul id="MDICdrugs"></ul>
              </div>
            </div><!--//MDICilfulllist-->
          </div><!--//intcheck_inputbox-->
        </div><!--//intc-search-->


The source code looks like this

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **~ (tilde)** as this page suggest it :

[SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/ff821075.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, If you are using `SendKeys`, you are doing something wrong.

`SendKeys` is an extremely fragile function, and there are usually other "programmatic" methods

## My Advice: Use the Page's javascript

I analyzed `http://reference.medscape.com/drug-interactionchecker` for you,

It turns out that the `handleKeyDown` function is bound to the `onkeydown` event,

You can simply simulate the `{ENTER}` key by calling it directly

```
handleKeyDown({which:13,preventDefault:function(){}});
```

(You can verify that it works by typing it in your browser's console)

You could call the function from vba with:

```
IE.Document.parentwindow.execscript "handleKeyDown({which:13,preventDefault:function(){}});"
```

Comment: still it is not working for me. Maybe I inserted it incorrectly in the code?

Comment: What's not working ? did you try to test the code in a browser first ?

Comment: I am using excel, how do i test it on the browser please?

Comment: The excel runs `VBA` that automates Internet explorer, that in turn, runs `Javascript` that simulates the `keydown=13` event, If the code doesn't work on your machine, break it down into parts and test it first only within the IE, to start the console press F12

Answer (score 0):

Sub FillInternetForm()

Dim IE As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Navigate "http://reference.medscape.com/drug-interactionchecker"

IE.Visible = True

While IE.Busy

DoEvents

Wend

Set TrackID = IE.Document.getelementbyid("MDICtextbox")

TrackID.Value = "aspirin"

IE.Visible = True

'Application.SendKeys ("{ENTER}")

IE.Document.parentwindow.execscript "handleKeyDown({which:13,preventDefault:function(){}});"

End Sub

Comment: It would help your answer if you could explain how the change to the code fixes the problem.